# Highcharts error 14 in chart from HTML table

Tags: highcharts

I'm using the highcharts data module to build a chart from an html table. In the data configuration of the chart I just have:

```
data: {
    table: table
}
```

But if I have string values such as "null", "NA", or even comma separators in the HTML table I get highcharts error 14, 'string value passed to chart...'

What I've tried:

Since HC should be able to handle null values I replaced NA will null in the tables. I also tried just leaving the blanks "" blank. But the issue is with the thousand separators. So I added thousandsSep: ',' hoping the chart output would understand that commas are part of the display but that doesn't work.

My next thought was to use a formatter function:

```
data: {
    table: function(){...change strings to float etc}
}
```

None of my attempts at the latter seem to work as I can't figure out what the data object looks like when accessed from a table. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What kinds of non-integer values can appear in your table? You mention "NA" and numbers with thousand separators ("1,234.00"). Are those all the other formats? In any case a JSFiddle helps a lot in resolving the issue.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/erd7236x/

Answer (score 0):

A solution that seems to have fixed the issue was to add a "parsed" function here is the api reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.parsed

I added the following to the data property:

```
data: {
        table: 'datatable',
        parsed: function()
        {
         var chartData = this.columns;
         var nData = [];
         for(var a in chartData)
         {
            var tempArray = [];
            for(var e in chartData[a])
          {
            var v = chartData[a][e].replace(/\,/g,"").replace("NA","0");
            /\d/g.test(v) == true ? v = parseFloat(v) : v = v;
            tempArray.push(v);
          }
          nData.push(tempArray);
         }
         this.columns = nData;
         //alert(JSON.stringify(nData));
         //this.columns = [];
         //this.columns.push(nData[0]);
         //this.columns.push(nData[1]);
        }
    },
```

...etc